# JavaScript does not work in View MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to high-line the row with id=2 by changing background color of a row. I used JavaScript in View, but it did change anything after running code. Here is my code.

```
<table class="GoalDistribution">
@{var i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <tr id = "@i">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.ORDER_NO, "MKP_003", "MKP_003", new { id = item.ORDER_NO }, new { })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MODEL)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PJNO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DELIVERY_DESTINATION)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PRODUCT_START_DATE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FINISH_FLAG)
        </td>

    </tr>
    i++;
    if (item.PJNO == "100") { 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".GoalDistribution #@(i)").css("background","yellow")
             </script>
    };
}
</table>
```

When I debug, Data loading successfully.
and by the way: Is this the best way to do this job. Can i handle it in controller. Thank you so much!

Comment: Remove the inline script, and just add a single script at the bottom of the page - `$(".GoalDistribution #2").css("background","yellow")`

Comment: Try it like following

**$(".GoalDistribution #" + i).css("background-color","yellow")**

Comment: i tried but it didn't work

Comment: You are having the id as `item.ORDER_NO` . Please check whether it contains the value or not.

Comment: i debug, data is ok.

Comment: Read all the comments and answers. DO NOT render the script inline. Put it at the bottom of the page. If you have set it up correctly, `jquery.js` will be at the bottom of the page so this wont work since jquery has not even been loaded at that point.

Comment: thanks Stephen When I put code at the bottom. It works

Comment: You don't really need javascript for this. After the `@foreach` line add `var className = item.PJNO == "100" ? "selected" : null;` and then `<tr class="@selected">` then add a css definition for `.selected { background-color: yellow; }`

Comment: Do you mean <tr class="@className"> Stephen?

Comment: @TranDuyLinh, Oops - yes I did.

Comment: Its very useful. I know another way to solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, in this way . just add a class to `tr` when `i=1`. write your scriot.

```
 i++;
 @if(i == 2)
 {
   <tr class="bgYellow">
 }else
 {
   <tr>
 }
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.ORDER_NO, "MKP_003", "MKP_003", new { id = item.ORDER_NO }, new { })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MODEL)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PJNO)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DELIVERY_DESTINATION)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PRODUCT_START_DATE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FINISH_FLAG)
        </td>

    </tr>
```

and use this script

```
<script>
    $(documet).ready(function(){
        $(".GoalDistribution).find('.bgYellow').css("background","yellow")
    });
    </script>
```

Note: Id should not start with number. write this script either at bottom of page or at top.